# Is it possible to have different Firebase database rules for different apps?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have 2 different **apps** in one Firebase **project**.

Application A: com.example.A

Application B: com.example.B

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Are my current rules.

The problem is, one application should have the above rules, while another application should have it secured, with authentication-only.

So, how can I do it?

Comment: Are both apps reading from the same locations in the database?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  In a Firebase project, all apps share the same set of users and the same instance of Realtime Database with the rules for all those users.  There's no rule for targeting particular apps within the project with special access.  This is unlike some other features of Firebase, such as Remote Config that *do* allow you target different apps with different settings.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to filter by app but to filter by protecting a node. The application which is not required to login could validate by sending a boolean param in the model:

```
public class YourModel {
    //everything you need
    private boolean protection = false;
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data